# How to define Html.BeginForm for action with attribute routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

### Controller

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/search/{clause}/{skip?}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Search(string clause, int skip = 0)
{
   ...
}
```

### View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "search", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("clause", null, new { @class = "form-control col-md-4" })
    ...
}
```

### Rendered Html

```
<form action="/search" method="get">
    <input id="clause" name="clause" type="text" value="test">
</form>
```

I am using `[HttpGet]` partly because i want the search to be accessing via `http://myapp.com/search/<search values>`

When i navigate to `http://myapp.com/search/test`, everything seems fine, but when i try to enter my new search term in the textbox and hit enter or submit, it navigates to `http://myapp.com/search?clause=newsearch`

What should I do so that my textbox will navigate to `http://myapp.com/search/newsearch` instead?

Comment: you have to change routeconfig for this purpose.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad i am already using `HttpGet`

Comment: There's no provided way in MVC to change a form's action url real time on client side from what I know. You will have to add some javascript hack yourself. Is that an option for you?

Comment: post your global.asax

Comment: If there's no simple out of the box when, then I'll go ahead with the current implementation

Answer (score 0):

Your form generates `http://myapp.com/search?clause=newsearch` because a browser has no knowledge of your routes (c# code running on your server).

In order to generate your preferred url (`http://myapp.com/search/newsearch`), you need javascript to intercept and cancel the default submit, and build a url to navigate to. Using jQuery:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    var baseUrl = $(this).attr('action'); // or var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "search")';
    var url = baseUrl + '/' + $('clause').val(); // add value for skip if required
    location.href = url; // redirect
    return false; // cancel the default submit
});
```