# Form w/ method get matching route with segments for Model Parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is it possible to send a form with bound control's values to a route matching it's URL segments.

Usually a form would be send to 'Form?Category=cat24&Search=sea11' when transmitted with method GET. Is it possible to send the form to 'Form/cat24/sea11'.

The configured ASP.NET MVC route allows both ways.

Sample Code:

The form:

```
<form asp-action="Index" method="get">
    category <input asp-for="Category" /><br />
    search <input asp-for="Search" /><br />
    <button type="submit">send</button>
</form>
```

The Controller:

```
public class FormController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Index(SearchViewModel model)
    {
        var elem1 = model?.Search;
        var elem2 = model?.Category;
        if (elem1 != null)
            model.Results.Add(elem1);
        if (elem2 != null)
            model.Results.Add(elem2);
        // Do Search

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

The model:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
    public string Search { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }

    public IList<object> Results { get; set; } = new List<object>();
}
```

The route config:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "form",
    template: "Form/{category?}/{search?}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Form", action = "Index" });
```

Comment: The browser knows nothing about the route definitions on your server. The only way is to user javascript to intercept the submit and generate your own url - refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25886562/how-to-define-html-beginform-for-action-with-attribute-routing/40560391#40560391)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want isn't possible because url generation occurs on client side and according to [RFC1866](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1866.txt):

> To process a form whose action URL is an HTTP URL and whose method is 
>   `GET', the user agent starts with the action URI and appends a`?'
>   and the form data set, in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded' format
>   as above. The user agent then traverses the link to this URI just as
>   if it were an anchor (see 7.2, "Activation of Hyperlinks").

So it seems there is no way to send url as you want. Only way coming to my mind is to use javascript.

Comment: thanks, thorough answer with RFC reference - accepted